# Supervisord RPC - UNKNOWN_METHOD on any request

Tags: python, xml-rpc, supervisord

I've configured (almost default) supervisord.conf and started supervisord. Tasks launched and xmlrpc interfaces are up, but gives
`xmlrpclib.Fault: <Fault 1: 'UNKNOWN_METHOD'>` on evey xmlrpc request, even when launching supervisorctl itself.

There is a same message in the log:

```
TRAC XML-RPC method called: supervisor.getAllProcessInfo()
TRAC XML-RPC method supervisor.getAllProcessInfo() returned fault: [1] UNKNOWN_METHOD
TRAC 127.0.0.1:44458 - - [11/Nov/2009:09:51:02 +0300] "POST /RPC2 HTTP/1.1" 200 391
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect you removed these lines from the supervisord.conf config file:

```
; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface
```

Comment: this works. i was writing config entirely from scratch and didn't knew about this section. thanks.